# Where are templates for asp.net core 2.0 mvc views

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to add custom templates to my asp.net core 2.0 mvc app but I'm not finding the templates.  I only see the 1.0/1.1 templates in Users{user}.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2017 and asp.net Core 2.0, I have found the Templates in this place:

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc\2.0.X\Templates`

Where "x" is the version number.